# Divisor over ellitptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I struggle to prove the following theorem :

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$. Let $D=\sum n_p P$ be a divisor on $E$. Then $D \sim 0$ if and only if $\sum [n_p]P=\mathcal{O}$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the neutral for the group law of the curve.

Comment: See prop 3.4 & cor 3.5 in Silverman: http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf

Comment: Chapter III, sorry!